# Search Contract ListView always selecting first item in list

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

My Search Contract populates a SearchContractResultsPages `resultsList` with objects, however when I try to select an item (which opens other page and passes the selection as a navigation parameter), the first item is always selected and passed as the parameter. I simply have no idea what to do to fix this, or what code needs changing, the `resultsListView.SelectedItem` is always the item opened, no matter what I actually select. The selection logic is carried out on the `DoubleTapped` event.

I don't know what code to post, so if anyone has any ideas, I will happily post I relevant parts you need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a cop-out before I answer, but it depends...

If you are navigating to another page on SelectedItemChanged, the selected item should probably already be the correct one and you can use that as your navigation parameter.  If this isn't working we will need to see more (come) code.

If you have an ItemClick event handler on the list view, you should use e.ClickedItem to get the correct reference back.  Again, if this is what you are doing and it isn't working, we will need to see code.

Ah, I see you are switching selections on Double tapping the item.  This could be the cause of your problem.  Double-clicking to select is not one of the usual ways to select an item in a list.  You should probably stick with the "small swipe" to select, as virtually all other apps in the ecosystem do.  Not only will this let you verify what selection you have made before doing anything with it, but it will not confuse users since they're already used to the paradigm.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea that using the `DoubleTapped` event instead would cause such a problem. Using the `ItemClicked` event works absolutely fine.